# While downloading a file need to show progressing

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I created one web page, its in there one grid view control(see attached[image] image) in that grid view one link button(Download) . if i click download button file will download . downloading time is little far so i need to show progressing (like still downloading ...) . 
  I used update panel, update progress controls its not working for me,  and i used image control also that one also doesn't help me. 
   Give me some tips to show progressing msg.. please .

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of the options you can take:

1. write ashx generic handler that will monitor byte to byte procesing
   Inside this handler save current procesing position. Call this ashx to download file.
2. write server side function that will return current procesing position saved by the ashx handler
   This function must be awailable to javascript
3. on client side just call this javascript function that calls server side function

This is the whole concept. Please let me know if I need to explain you something in details.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/115491-download-file-asynchronously-with-progressbar/

Comment: I don't think this windows app solution will do the job for asp.net problem. Only if soundy decides to write .net activex component.